# Applying Newton's second law to a moving block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I need some clarification about Newton's second law in the following situation:

A right triangle-shaped wedge with mass $M$ rests on a frictionless, horizontal tabletop. A block with mass $m$ is placed on the wedge. The wedge has a slope with angle $\alpha$. There is no friction between the block and the wedge. The system is released from rest.

There is contact force between the block and the wedge so the net horizontal force on the wedge has magnitude $n\text{sin}(\alpha)$ where $n$ is the contact force between the wedge and the block. Now I want to find the contact force $n$.

If I drew a free body diagram of the block, I would get that $n = mg\text{cos}(\alpha)$ because the block is not moving in the direction perpendicular to the face of the wedge. However, this is **incorrect**, right? The block itself will be accelerating so we cannot use Newton's second law in its frame of reference, we would have to choose a frame of an observer not on the block and not on the wedge to use Newton's second law.

Comment: the equation from your diagram is correct. The net along-the-wedge force, though,  is: $f=ma=mg*sin(\alpha)$, rather than  $f=n*sin(\alpha)$

Comment: What diagram are you referring to?

Comment: "If I drew a free body diagram of the block, I would get that n=mgcos(α)
 because"

Comment: But your frame of reference is the wedge, not the block. It is inertial. The block is accelerating under the force in your frame (the wedge)

Comment: Why is the wedge an inertial frame of reference? It is also accelerating. I think we need to use the table as a frame of reference.

Comment: Ohhh I am so sorry, I misread the problem. Let me think about it again.

Comment: Do you know what a pseudo force is?

Comment: @StutiGupta No, I don't know what a pseudo force is. Do I need to use that concept?

Comment: It would be helpful in telling you why you can't draw an FBD from reference frame of the wedge, as well as in solving the original question. But you can only draw an FBD from the reference frame of an observer on ground, not the wedge, if you're not familiar with what a pseudo force is

Comment: You can look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force